# Calling Objects inside other Objects, MTGJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, object

Struggling again i'm afraid. 
I have accessed a resources online called MTG JSON (http://mtgjson.com/), which is a json file that contains information about every single Magic the Gathering Card every printed.

Now the information that i have is the card name, and i want to get the multiverse id. If this information was located in the AllCards.json file this would be quite simple, however It is stored in the AllSets.json, which means i need to do some digging through objects.

I am very new to javascript, so getting this far has been quite the accomplishment, but i am absolutely stumped and in need of aid.

So, first the code. I have currently come up with this to read the file:

```
        $.getJSON("AllSets.json", function(json) {

            console.log(json); 

            Sets = Object.keys(json);
            i = 0;


            while (i < Sets.length){
                currentSet = Sets[i];
                console.log(json.currentSet);
                console.log(currentSet);
                console.log(i);
                i = i + 1;

            }


        });
```

And I have started to move through the sets in order to find the card that i am currently on by name.

The issue is the following three lines:

```
                console.log(json.currentSet);

                console.log(currentSet);

                console.log(i);
```

these are the ones giving me the biggest headache, as both i and currentSet are doing their jobs fine, returning the current set and the corrent position on that set in the list. however json.currentSet is returning as `undefined`.

For those that are interested in the structure of the JSON:

```
        "SOI","releaseDate":"2016-04-08","border":"black","type":"expansion","block":"Shadows over Innistrad","booster":[["rare","mythic rare"],"uncommon","uncommon","uncommon","common","common","common","common","common","common","common","common","common","common","land","marketing"],"translations":{"de":"Schatten über Innistrad","fr":"Ténèbres sur Innistrad","it":"Ombre su Innistrad","es":"Sombras sobre Innistrad","pt":"Sombras em Innistrad","jp":"イニストラードを覆う影","cn":"依尼翠暗影","ru":"Тени над Иннистрадом","ko":"이니스트라드에 드리운 그림자"},"cards":[{"artist":"Chase Stone","cmc":3,"colorIdentity":["W"],"colors":["White"],"flavor":"\"We pray to Avacyn on high.\nOn snow-white wings fearless you fly.\nKeep safe our souls. Keep safe our lives.\nMay angels watch us from the skies.\"\n—Children's prayer","id":"c053a8c64d8c2ff2f17e4306344f353b46cd7352","imageName":"always watching","layout":"normal","manaCost":"{1}{W}{W}","multiverseid":409737,"name":"Always Watching","number":"1","rarity":"Rare","text":"Nontoken creatures you control get +1/+1 and have vigilance.","type":"Enchantment","types":["Enchantment"]},{"artist":"Joseph Meehan","cmc":8,"colorIdentity":["W"],"colors":["White"],"id":"80673365be1e340436928050e487afe0d2a70539","imageName":"angel of deliverance","layout":"normal","manaCost":"{6}{W}{W}","multiverseid":409738
```

Any feedback, criticism, advice etc. would be greatly appreciated, as every time i think i make a mile, i see another 10 miles ahead.

Comment: The question, as asked, is unclear and requires knowledge of the structure of AllSets.json and AllCards.json. I think you'll have better luck getting an answer if you genericize the question and provide two short sample json strings that are similar to your actual strings but with most of the unnecessary cruft cut out for viewers to work with.

Comment: I am not really too familiar with this structure myself, but i will try to re post more generally. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use something like that

```
cards.forEach(function(e){
   if(e.name == "myName")
      console.log(e.multiverseid);
});
```

Comment: I cannot see the cards until i have opened the Set that they are in, but i think this will work once i have opened the Set.